# Using synapse spark db as a source in copy activity

Tags: azure-data-factory, serverless, azure-synapse-analytics

I have a synapse spark db using the delta format. When I try to create a linked service using either Synapse or Sql using its sql end point it does not allow it. Has any one come across that?

I need to move the data from a synapse lake database to an on prem db. Therefore I was planning to use a copy activity. I can access the parquet files on the data lake using ADLS G2 service. Is there a way of using synapse spark db end point?

Comment: Is your synapse spark pool up when you are trying to access the spark DB with Data Factory?

Comment: Can you provide your approach, Provide your sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Synapse Analytics, connecting directly to a lake database,similar to connecting to a dedicated SQL pool, is not possible. Instead, lake databases in Azure Synapse Analytics store their data within an Azure Data Lake Storage account. This is achieved by utilizing a linked service to the data lake storage account. By default, the data lake account created during the creation of the Synapse workspace is used to store all the data of the lake database.

- When working with Azure Synapse, creating a linked service using Synapse or SQL endpoints for a Synapse Spark DB in Delta format is currently not supported.

You can refer to this [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/database-designer/concepts-lake-database) to understand about the Lake Databases.

- One option is to use the Copy Activity in Azure Data Factory. Since you mentioned that you can access the parquet files on the data lake using the ADLS G2 service, you can leverage this to move the data.The Copy Activity supports various data sources and destinations,including Parquet files.

[image]
As you mentioned you need to move parquet files to on prem I have used synapse ADLS linked service and used Azure SQL database as sink.
[image]

**Copy activity:**
[image]

[image]

To access the data stored in the Azure Data Lake database in Azure Synapse, you can create a linked service to the data lake storage account.
This will allow you to establish a connection and interact with the data lake.

By creating a linked service, you will have the necessary access and permissions to query and work with the data stored in the Azure Data Lake database.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am already using the ADLS connection to Parquet files. But What I am trying to achieve is to connect to the end Point and be able to query the data like SQL. I am able to access this data as tables via SSMS installed locally. But cannot access it from any where other than that.

Comment: When working with Azure Synapse, creating a linked service using Synapse or SQL endpoints for a Synapse Spark DB in Delta format is currently not supported.